# How to import font awesome when I create a VuePress theme?

Tags: vue.js, web-frontend, vuepress

[image]

[image]

I'm new to Vue and VuePress. I checked Stylus doc and it says css files can be imported to Stylus files. However it won't work normally in this situation.
Can any one tell me how to import fontawesome in this case?